# Script inclusion in index.html on Vue.js application gives 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

My application has been simply generated by running this command:

```
vue init webpack
```

The template application has only `vue-router` installed by answering "Y" on the forth question of the wizard.

I want to include jquery from `node_modules` folder:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

then I add this

```
<head>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

on the `index.html` page.

Next step:

```
npm run dev
```

application starts up correctly but I got 404 on `jquery.js`.

I had never touched anything in the whole application except for that line in `index.html`.

We have the same problem in a bigger application but we had no idea if we could reproduce on a smaller one... but we managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import it in your component. webpack manage the dependencies.

If you have used `vue init webpack` you are also using **vue-loader** so for adding jquery to the Hallo component you can do like this

first as you have already done `npm install --save jquery`

After that open the file App.vue and in the  section add the import:

```
<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'
import jquery from 'jquery'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  }
}
</script>
```

Not sure is what are you looking for but this is how you can add a 3rd party lib